# Zero key on Samsung laptop number pad not working

Tags: windows, laptop, numlock

On my Samsung Laptop NP550P5C, sometimes when I press the number pad `0`, it simply does not return the number zero. Instead it acts like a right-click.

I tried switching the `Num Lock`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I had to google around quite a bit to find a solution. So this is for posterity.</sub>

On Samsung laptops, it can be solved by switching the `Fn Lock` key, which is found on the right side of the `F12` key.